# Set Safari's default search engine to Google UK

Tags: macos, safari, google

How can I change Safari's default search engine to google.co.uk?

Currently when I search in the address bar the results are always from google.com.

Also if I highlight a term in Safari, right click and select "search with Google" it's from the US site.

If I scroll to the foot of the search results page it says "United Kingdom" at the bottom, and gives my location accurately based on my Android phone's location, but it's not actually using Google.co.uk.

If I select preferences, I only have Google, DuckDuckGo, Bing, and Yahoo listed. Is there any way that I can customise this list?

Comment: Try [GLIMS](http://www.machangout.com/), if it still works with the current version of Safari. It can, among others, let you insert a different search engine.

Comment: I read somewhere that if you are *IN* the UK and end up on google.com there is a link at the bottom of the page to switch to google.co.uk. Unfortunately I cant test this and see...

Comment: I spoke to Apple support, and they said the same. It says "United Kingdom" at the foot of the page, but the prices are all in $ and the link to copy is .com

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cookies and cache?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [AnySearch](https://github.com/mcs07/AnySearch-safari-extension) Safari extension which will allow you to set custom search engines to be used as the default.

Add this as a search engine in AnySearch: `https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=@@@`